# Загрузка и удаление изображения

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы при загрузке новой фотки удалялась старая (из бд и сервера)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удаляйте файл через unlink и делайте UPDATE записи в БД:

```
unlink("file.gif");

$Query = "UPDATE `table` SET avatar='..' WHERE .. ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Надо удалить старую, потом загрузить новую и обновить название в БД.
А вообще, сформулируйте вопрос четче, чтобы получить более развернутый ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Кстати,**ling** правильно написал, сформулируй проблему и получишь адекватный ответ.

А то как-то непонятно ты имеешь ввиду только БД или БД и файловую систему.